# Mean reverting Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

A mean reverting Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE is given by
$$=(−)+;_0=,$$
where m and  are positive constants and  is a standard Brownian motion in 1 dimension. I have obtained the solution of this equation, $$X_t = xe^{-t} + m(1-e^{-t}) + \sigma \int_0^t e^{-(t-s)} dW_s.$$ My questions are:
Is my solution correct?
What is the long time behaviour of the solution?
How to obtain the equation of the second moment?

Comment: What do you mean by equation of the second moment ?

Comment: I think the second moment is also known as the variance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Variance

Comment: I know what is that the second moment (and is not the variance. The variance is the centred second moment). But what is the "equation of the second moment" ? If you look for the variance, then my answer below allow you to compute the variance of $X_t$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for your explanation. What I mean by "the equation of the second moment" should be the equation obtained by evaluating $M_n(t)=E(X_t^n)$ where $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I didn't check into detail the solution you found, but at least, the solution is something of this form. Now, one can prove that if $f\in L^2[0,t]$, then $$\int_0^tf(s)\,\mathrm d W_s\sim \mathcal N\left(0,\int_0^t f(s)^2\,\mathrm d s\right).$$